# How do I visualize a data.tree with values in R?

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, networkd3, data.tree

As mentioned in title, how do I plot a data.tree with its relevant values?

Thank you in advance for the help. Already at my wits end :(

Edit: More information:

The data I am trying to visualize is a survey, which the respondent is asked the primary question, in which if h/she answered yes and there will be follow up questions to the first one. I am trying to visualize the percentage of respondents who answered yes or no to each question to which my idea is to use a decision tree like plot for that.

```
library(data.tree)
library(networkD3)

# create simple tree
tree <- Node$new("Primary Node")
tree1 <- tree$AddChild("Tree1")
tree2 <- tree$AddChild("Tree2")
tree3 <- tree1$AddChild("Tree3")
tree4 <- tree2$AddChild("Tree4")

# assign value

tree1$value <- 1
tree2$value <- 2
tree3$value <- 3
tree4$value <- 4

# plot tree ## No values reflected
plot(tree)
simpleNetwork(ToDataFrameNetwork(tree))
```

Edit:

Tried your solution, Gilean, works pretty good, however, how do I get the child node to recognize same words as different trees? And how do I adjust the words by font size or alignment so it won't impede visualization?

```r
library(igraph)

# requires the changing of No to No1, No2 and so forth to prevent it merging into one large node

df <- data.frame(parent = c("Have you ever had your cholesterol  fat levels in your blood  measured by a doctor or other health worker",
                            "Have you ever had your cholesterol  fat levels in your blood  measured by a doctor or other health worker",
                            "Have you ever been told by a doctor or other health worker that you have raised cholesterol",
                            "Have you ever been told by a doctor or other health worker that you have raised cholesterol",
                            "Were you first told in the past 12 months",
                            "Were you first told in the past 12 months",
                            "In the past two weeks have you taken any oral treatment medication for raised total cholesterol prescribed by a doctor or other health worker",
                            "In the past two weeks have you taken any oral treatment medication for raised total cholesterol prescribed by a doctor or other health worker",
                            "Have you ever seen a traditional healer for raised cholesterol",
                            "Have you ever seen a traditional healer for raised cholesterol",
                            "Are you currently taking any herbal or traditional remedy for your raised cholesterol",
                            "Are you currently taking any herbal or traditional remedy for your raised cholesterol"),

                          child = c("No", "Have you ever been told by a doctor or other health worker that you have raised cholesterol", 
                           "No1", "Were you first told in the past 12 months",
                           "No2", "In the past two weeks have you taken any oral treatment medication for raised total cholesterol prescribed by a doctor or other health worker",
                           "No3", "Have you ever seen a traditional healer for raised cholesterol",
                           "No4", "Are you currently taking any herbal or traditional remedy for your raised cholesterol",
                           "No5", "Yes"),

                 value = 1:12)


tree <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = TRUE)

plot(tree, vertex.label = V(tree)$name, edge.label = E(tree)$value, layout=layout_as_tree, vertex.size = c(10, E(tree)$value))
```

Comment: Is `data.tree` a requirement or would another package like `igraph` be okay as well?

Comment: Yes please. I am using data.tree just because it is the first option that popup in Google.

Comment: If you type in `?igraph.plotting` in your console, you can see all parameters you can adjust in your plot. For fontsize you want to use `vertex.label.cex` and for alignment a combination of `vertex.label.dist` and `vertex.label.angle`. For your other problem. Right now node label and node names are identical in your second example. If you create your data.frame with unique node names, you can use `vertex.label` to assign non-unique node labels afterwards.

Comment: In the future it might be better to ask further questions as a separate question instead of editing your original question, so more users can help you and other users can find your question if they look for a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `data.tree`, so I do not know a way to add a fast way to add all labels, but you can set a label for each edge separately.

```
library(data.tree)

# create simple tree
tree <- Node$new("Primary Node")
tree1 <- tree$AddChild("Tree1")
tree2 <- tree$AddChild("Tree2")
tree3 <- tree1$AddChild("Tree3")
tree4 <- tree2$AddChild("Tree4")

# add edges 
SetEdgeStyle(tree, label = 1)
SetEdgeStyle(tree2, label = 2)
SetEdgeStyle(tree3, label = 3)
SetEdgeStyle(tree4, label = 4)

# plot tree 
plot(tree)
```

In `igraph` you can just create a `data.frame` with all the information you need and create a graph with a tree-structure from this data.frame with the edge labels. However, it will be necessary to adjust a few more things to make it look nice in comparison to `data.tree`.

```
library(igraph)
df <- data.frame(parent = c("Primary Node", "Primary Node", "Tree1", "Tree2"),
                 child = c("Tree1", "Tree2", "Tree3", "Tree4"),
                 value = 1:4)

tree <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = TRUE)

plot(tree, vertex.label = V(tree)$name, edge.label = E(tree)$value, layout=layout_as_tree, vertex.size = c(20, E(tree)$value * 10))
```

Comment: Ohh, this is good, Thank you. Is there any way the tree nodes can be dynamically resized based on the value? e.g. Tree 1 value 1 = smallest node, while Tree 4 value 4 = biggest node.

Comment: I added the parameter `vertex.size` in the `igraph`-solution to change the node sizes based on value.

Comment: Hi @Gilean0709, tried your solutions, works pretty good, just need some minor improvement. Posted the code in the original comment. Thanks for the help.